# MySQL ensure each row is unique

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have following table and want to make sure that each row is unique. The combination of sku_simple_product, branding_position_de, branding_id, handling_group_id and pre_cost_id must only exist once in this table.

```
branding_position_id    int(255) Auto-Inkrement  
sku_simple_product  text     
branding_position_de    text     
branding_position_en    text NULL    
branding_position_fr    text NULL    
branding_position_es    text NULL    
branding_position_it    text NULL    
branding_position_pl    text NULL    
branding_position_nl    text NULL    
branding_id varchar(255)     
handling_group_id   varchar(255) NULL    
is_branding_incl    int(11) [0]  
pre_cost_id varchar(255)
```

Now I have the following questions:

1. sure this by SQL contrains?
2. Do I actually need the auto created "branding_position_id"?
3. What is the most efficient way to insert
   a record if not existing or update the record if it is existing
   without knowing its unique "branding_position_id"? So based on the
   above described unique combination of attributes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `int(255)` supposed to mean!?!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UNIQUE` constraint, as in:

```
alter table my_table add constraint uq1 (
  sku_simple_product, 
  branding_position_de, 
  branding_id, 
  handling_group_id,
  pre_cost_id
);
```

However, this solution has the potential to be highly ineficient, since the data type of the columns is `TEXT`. A `TEXT` column can store very big pieces of text, and checking their uniqueness can be slow.

If possible, I would suggest changing the type to a smaller one, like `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is the difference between VARCHAR and Text? I expect the length of each column up to max 150 characters long.
Regarding performance, does this mean it will slow down inserting data only or also reading data?
What happens if I add this constraint to my table and I have some data which is not unique? Is there an efficient way to clean it up?

Comment: The `TEXT` data type stores up to 64k bytes, while `VARCHAR` usual lenght is smaller than 255 chars. I would use `VARCHAR` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

2. Yes, because all your other data can change over time and is also more efficient. Here you can see some [advantages and disavantages.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)
3. You can use something like this.

```
INSERT INTO companies
    (id, full_name, address, phone_number)
VALUES
    (1, ‘Apple’, '1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, California', 18002752273)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    full_name = ‘Apple’
    address = ‘1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, California’
    phone_number = 18002752273;
```

Comment: Or, avoid repeating the text by using `VALUES()`:  `... UPDATE full_name = VALUE(full_name), address = VALUES(address), ...`